# Value Error Invalid Literal with Base 10 - Scrapy

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape this data but running into some issues as the title notes.

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I think I understand the problem, in that it is finding something that isn't an integer, looks like a blank space of some sorts that it can't turn into an integer.   Do i need to do some additional cleaning of the data before I try to sum or anything else i might be missing here?

```
class PsaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 't3'
    allowed_domains = ['psacard.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.psacard.com/Pop/GetItemTable?headingID=51453&categoryID=20003&isPSADNA=false&pf=0&_=1555080293549']

    def parse(self, response):
        def strip_second(sel, xpath):
            try:
                return sum([int(x.strip().replace(',', '')) for x in sel.xpath(xpath).extract() if u'-' not in x])
            except ValueError:
                pass 

        rows = response.css('table.pop-grid tbody tr')
        for row in rows:
            td = row.css('td')[0]
            yield {
            'name' : row.xpath('td[2]/strong//text()').extract_first(),
            'auth': strip_second(row, 'td[4]//text()'),
            'psa1': strip_second(row, 'td[5]//text()'),
            'psa1.5': strip_second(row, 'td[6]//text()'),
            'psa2': strip_second(row, 'td[7]//text()'),
            'psa3': strip_second(row, 'td[8]//text()'),
            'psa4': strip_second(row, 'td[9]//text()'),
            'psa5': strip_second(row, 'td[10]//text()'),
            'psa6': strip_second(row, 'td[11]//text()'),
            'psa7': strip_second(row, 'td[12]//text()'),
            'psa8': strip_second(row, 'td[13]//text()'),
            'psa9': strip_second(row, 'td[14]//text()'),
            'psa10': strip_second(row, 'td[15]//text()'),
            }
```

Comment: maybe do something like `int(x.strip().replace(',', '') or 0)` if what you get there is an empty string. If not, then you'll have to clean that string better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug what you get in your data. Strip wrong data at least with:

```
data = [x.strip().replace(',', '') for x in sel.xpath(xpath).extract() if u'-' not in x]
return sum([int(x) for x in data if x])
```